# Preventing click event navigating back to recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I have a `recyclerview` which contains `imageview`, `textview` and an `floating action button` for which I've attached `addOnItemTouchListener` event to navigate to `fullscreen view`. Alongside, I have a `click event` attached to `floating action button` inside `recyclerview`.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new GalleryAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new GalleryAdapter.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SlideshowDialogFragment newFragment = SlideshowDialogFragment.newInstance();
        newFragment.show(ft, "slideshow");
    }
    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

    }
}));
```

Below is my `FAB` inside `RecyclerView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/select_cake"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and `clickevent` in `GalleryAdapter`

```
view.findViewById(R.id.select_cake).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
          Toast.makeText(mContext,"Test Toast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
});
```

But, whenever I click on `FAB`, the toast gets displayed, but it also navigates to other view through `recyclerView's ItemTouchListner`

I've used `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` and `android:clickable="true"` for `FAB`, but still the event navigates to its parent `recyclerView` and hence executing lines of code written for `recyclerItemClick`. How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: You could use a flag and set it to true when one is executed. And check for the value of flag in the other onClick and execute it when flag is not set to true.

Comment: @AlphaQ Agreed with this method, but there has to be some way to deal with this.. :)